# What does False Positive mean in bio-metric authentication systems context?

Tags: authentication, biometrics

In bio-metric authentication systems, what do **False Positive** and **False Negative** terms mean?

Do they have any relation to **False Accept** and **False Reject** terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A false positive is when the system incorrectly accepts a biometric sample as being a match. (Same as false accept)

A false negative is when a valid biometric sample is provided but the system falsely rejects it as not a match. (Same as false reject)

There is a inverse relationship between the two.  As you increase security (reduce false positives) you also increase the number of false rejects.

The same is true going the other direction. When you reduce false negatives, you also increase false positives.

Comment: Thanks dear mageos, but aren't they in reverse? As I've read from Security Encyclopedia, false positive is when the system incorrectly introduces something correct as false.

Comment: False positive simply means that the system grants a match when it really wasn't. In computer security, most of the time you are looking for a bad actor. The thing you are trying to identify is a network breach or virus. In these cases a false positive would be identifying something ok (non-virus) as a virus. In biometrics, you are trying to verify the identity of an individual. In this case a false positive is identifying not the person as the person. In other words, falsely giving a positive response.